# Delete duplicate entry row entirely in csv file based on the first id before delimiter |?

Tags: python, csv

Here I have a csv file:

```
b5711586dc018c1deed6b1ea596da304|f4e3945da368711abb3110b621ceada5c21c11f8|bdf7f718f579d64060c7739225de573e4ffda7fe8b10cdaaeb672de5b7c06  98e|2017-01-20 11:42:12|111|Relative|path
1beb1d0ac2d24cb87d8fe6ce05601136|f5ace00777f68909d106719629c85fb3af23b810|62f6ebb14ede7a1b6307cea5f58a18ff59282650af750a575d1bdb530c04f  11f|2017-01-20 11:42:12|111|Relative|path
b5711586dc018c1deed6b1ea596da304|f4e3945da368711abb3110b621ceada5c21c11f8|bdf7f718f579d64060c7739225de573e4ffda7fe8b10cdaaeb672de5b7c06  98e|2017-01-20 11:43:28|111|Relative|path
1beb1d0ac2d24cb87d8fe6ce05601136|f5ace00777f68909d106719629c85fb3af23b810|62f6ebb14ede7a1b6307cea5f58a18ff59282650af750a575d1bdb530c04f  11f|2017-01-20 11:43:28|111|Relative|path
b5711586dc018c1deed6b1ea596da304|f4e3945da368711abb3110b621ceada5c21c11f8|bdf7f718f579d64060c7739225de573e4ffda7fe8b10cdaaeb672de5b7c06  98e|2017-01-20 11:48:03|111|Relative|path
1beb1d0ac2d24cb87d8fe6ce05601136|f5ace00777f68909d106719629c85fb3af23b810|62f6ebb14ede7a1b6307cea5f58a18ff59282650af750a575d1bdb530c04f  11f|2017-01-20 11:48:03|111|Relative|path
```

But there are  redundant lines  which I  want to remove and keep only unique lines.

Is there any way to write a script in python to make  this?
I have used the following  script:

```
import csv
with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file.csv','rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: would you try to use pandas?

Comment: in the end, you want to store the data to csv or list?

Comment: @PoStevanusAndrianta agree with Po, it is much easier to use pandas. (though it is designed for analytical work)

Comment: you can read the lines into a list and convert the list into a set. That should remove the dup lines automatically.

Comment: With pandas: `pd.read_csv(file, header=None, sep='|').drop_duplicates([0,1,2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set` to remember all the rows already seen, and only print the ones not already in the set:

```
import csv
with open('a.csv','rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')  # need to specify delimiter
  rows_seen = set()
  for row in reader:
    row_key = row[0]
    if row_key not in rows_seen:
      print ', '.join(row) 
    rows_seen.add(row_key)
```

Also note you need to explicitly specify the delimiter (`|`) because it is a non-default one.

Comment: I want to remove the duplicate lines from the csv file,not just printing.

Comment: @SaiKiran you contradict yourself. Your code prints, you said you want to add it to DB, and now you say you want to change the file.  We can't help if you don't ask your question clearly..

Comment: @SaiKiran, also, you didn't explain in what sense the lines are "duplicate". all lines in the file you posted are different.

Comment: Don't just copy answers.

Comment: @hd1 what do you mean? what answer did I copy? Our answers are very different.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file.csv','r') as in_file, open('results/20_01_2017_db_unique_file.csv','w') as out_file:
    dupl = set()
    for line in in_file:
        if line in dupl: 

        dupl.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the lines as comma delimited format, you can read as regular lines and you would be able to hash the lines into a set.

This should work for you :

```
with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file.csv','rb') as f:
    line_set = set(f)

with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file_v2.csv', 'wb') as f:
    for line in line_set: f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do so like this:

```
import csv
new_rows = set()
with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    [new_rows.add(row) for row in reader]

with open('results/20_01_2017_db_fileUniq.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    [fout.writeline(r) for r in list(new_rows)]
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Why are you using list comprehensions instead of loops?

Comment: your solution does not preserve order. better to use an OrderedSet

Comment: @shx2 I'm used comprehensions for efficiency reasons. Also, how would you preserve order in a set anyway?

Comment: Comprehensions should not be used instead of plain loops. There are two reasons not to use it here: you don't need the list being created (the list can be very long, you don't need it), and the loop has a side effect (adds to a set).  For very big files, this is guaranteed to be slower. As for preserving order: either use an OrderedSet, or use the set differently. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
import csv
data = []
with open('results/20_01_2017_db_file.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if not row in data:
            data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new file containing unique lines only using a list:

```
def unique(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    unique_ids = []
    with open(input_file_path) as in_file, open(output_file_path, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            tokens = line.split('|',1)
            if tokens[0] not in unique_ids:
                unique_ids.append(tokens[0])
                out_file.write(line)
```

call it like so:

```
unique('path/to/input','path/to/output')
```